# Open SqueezeBox in joomla 1.5

Tags: javascript, php, popup, joomla1.5, squeezebox

Hi I'd like to open a popup with giver URL in my joomla 1.5
Well I try many solution to this but none work
Well I button that open a popup, the user fill the form and submit, after that I call a function to load the new inserted data 
Well the popup work fine here 
I add the `JHTML::_('behavior.modal');` 
Here the code that i use to open the popup to add something to the table

```
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 400}}" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="modal" target="_blank">
    <img class="button-20" src="components/com_tkcontrack/assets/images/new_client.png" title="<?php echo JText::_('TKCONTRACK_NOUVEAU'); ?>" />
</a>
```

here all work fine
well the data that I load using ajax containt a tr in that tr there is td that containt a `<a>` tag to open a popup to modify that item, and here is the code

```
<a rel="{handler: "iframe", size: {x: 600, y: 400}}" href="' . $url . '" class="modal toolbar" target="_blank" >';
```

Well here is the problem, when I clik on the url,in stead of open a popup it open a new window

In joomla 2.5 I used to call function that call the  `SqueezeBox.open` to open a popup but here in joomla 1.5 well I call it I have this errro message

**TypeError: SqueezeBox.open is not a function**

any help please

well I cant use JQuery because they ask me not to use it

Answer (score 0):

Update your link html with this one :

```
<a rel="{size: {x: 600, y: 400}, handler: 'iframe'}" href="' . $url . '" class="modal toolbar" target="_blank" >CONTENT</a>
```

If you want to modify the popup, then load these :

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
JHTML::_('script','modal.js', 'media/system/js', true);
JHTML::_('stylesheet','modal.css');
```